# В чем суть отличия между ссылочными и значимыми типами данных в C#?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

В чем суть отличия между ссылочными и значимыми типами данных в C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значимые типы хранят значение, а ссылочные - ссылку на значение.

```
class ByRef
{
    public byte Value { get; set; }
}

struct ByVal {
    public byte Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ByRef byRef = new ByRef { Value = 0 };
        ByVal byVal = new ByVal { Value = 0 };
    }
}
```

В этом коде и byRef, и byVal создаются как локальные переменные метода Main на стеке. Переменная byVal содержит значение Value, а переменная byRef содержит ссылку на значение Value, хранящееся на куче.

Comment: Главное отличие - это где храниться значение переменной. Для ссылочных типов - это куча, для значимых - это стек. При этом, ссылочная переменная (сама ссылка) храниться на стеке. Значимыми  могут быть только экземпляры структур, в противоположность им ссылочные - это экземпляры классов. Все встроенные типы (int, double и т.д.) - это структуры.

Answer (score 13):

Основное различие между ссылочными и значимыми типами данных — смысл равенства и копирования.

Для значимых типов при копировании вы получаете новый экземпляр, содержащий *копии* значений исходного экземпляра. Иными словами, экземпляры ведут себя *как значения*, например, как числа. Если вы скопировали значение, и изменили исходное значение, то эти изменения никак не отразятся на копии:

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
Point p2 = p1; // (1, 2)
p1.X = 100;
// p2.X всё ещё равно 1
```

Для ссылочных типов, копирование даёт вам новую *ссылку* на те же данные. Соответственно, если вы меняете объект ссылочного типа, то эти изменения становятся доступны по *любой* из ссылок на объект:

```
XElement e1 = new XElement("test") { Value = "hello" };
XElement e2 = e1;
e1.Value = "goodbye";
// e2.Value стало равно "goodbye"
```

Теперь, равенство. Одинаковые экземпляры типов-значений, не зависимо от того, являются ли они копиями одного общего объекта или нет, являются равными. Экземпляры ссылочных типов, даже если они содержат одинаковые данные, являются разными.

```
Point p1 = new Point(1, 2), p2 = new Point(1, 2);
// p1 == p2
```

```
XElement e1 = new XElement("test") { Value = "hello" },
         e2 = new XElement("test") { Value = "hello" };
// e1 != e2
```

Можно сказать, что объекты ссылочных типов обладают индивидуальностью, а объекты значимых типов — нет.

---

Разумеется, семантику сравнения можно кастомизировать, перегрузив оператор сравнения (и/или реализовав интерфейс `IEquatable<T>`). При этом можно, например, заставить ссылочный тип вести себя так, как будто бы он является значимым типом. И наоборот, храня данные значимого типа в неизменяемом поле ссылочного типа, можно заставить значимый тип вести себя как ссылочный.

---

Все остальные отличия являются лишь следствиями этих, главных отличий. То, что переменные ссылочного типа в Майкрософтовской реализации хранят внутри ссылку, есть по сути деталь имплементации. То, что экземпляры значимых типов *иногда* попадают на стек (а именно, когда они не являются полями классов, и не лежат в замыкании, `async`-методе или методе-генераторе), также [является деталью имплементации](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) (и может быть не так в будущих версиях или другой имплементации платформы .NET).

---

Если вы выбираете, использовать для вашего объекта структуру (значимый тип) или класс (ссылочный тип), задайте себе вопрос: являются ли два объекта с одинаковыми данными одним и тем же, или разными? Если это, к примеру, объекты, представляющие человека, и в данных у вас его имя, фамилия и возраст, то имеет смысл использовать класс: ведь два человека с одинаковыми именами всё ещё не являются одним и тем же человеком.

А если это, например, объект, представляющий рациональную дробь, то нету смысла разделять различные экземпляры дроби 3/8, так что тут уместно воспользоваться структурой.

Comment: я бы использовал слово реализация вместо имплементация. за ответ (+)

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Я хотел сохранить идиому «деталь имплементации», а так, конечно, «реализация» звучит более по-русски.

Answer (score 1):

Например, если присвоить переменной объект ссылочного типа, то в этой переменной будет только ссылка указывающая на обьект, а не само значение. А если присвоить объект значимого типа, то он скопируется.

Comment: Ну правильный же ответ.

Comment: @0xdb, ну он мне нравится даже больше принятого, потому что в принятом кусок кода не дописан до нормального примера. Хотя VladD как всегда лучше всех расписал :)

Comment: @0xdb, да, всё верно.