# Неверные данные? Баг C# или я что-то упустил?

Tags: c#, list, for

Есть двойной цикл for с проверкой внутри на совпадение с заранее добытым массивом id

Тоесть цикл добавляет в List объект из перебраного списка у которого совпал id

getInfo - внутренний метод класса который выводит содерживмое класса

dfood - список нужных id

masses - список значений которые нужно общитать и установить

temp - список всех id по одному

result - схожий по сути список как и temp (тоже List), но с повторениями

Если ещё вкратце, то готовый объект который нужно добавить верный, а при выходе их циклов там левые объекты (копии последних добавленых подобных)

```
for (int i = 0; i< dfood.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < temp.Count; j++)
        {
            if(temp[j].id == dfood[i])
            {
                food temp2 = temp[j];
                int c = temp2.cal;
                temp2.setCalory((int)(((double)c / 100) * masses[i]));

                result.Add(temp2);
                result[result.Count-1].getInfo();//выводит верную инфу 100%
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (food cal in result)
    {
        cal.getInfo(); // не верная инфа
    }
```

Собственно сам класс

```
class food
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string typePr;
    public int cal;
    public string desk;
    public food(int id_, string name_, string typePr_, int cal_, string desk_)
    {
        id = id_;
        name = name_;
        typePr = typePr_;
        cal = cal_;
        desk = desk_;
    }
    public void setCalory(int c)
    {
        cal = c;
    }
    public void getInfo()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("----------------");
        Debug.WriteLine("id: " + id);
        Debug.WriteLine("name: " + name);
        Debug.WriteLine("typePr: " + typePr);
        Debug.WriteLine("cals: " + cal);
        //Debug.WriteLine("desc: " + desk);
        Debug.WriteLine("----------------");
    }
}
```

Если врубить вот это дебаг-логирование в консоль, то я ожидал от последнего foreach увидеть примерно вот такое

```
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 238
----------------
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 240
----------------
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 242
----------------
```

Но на самом деле то вот так выходит. Хотя вывод в цикле, в условии такой как нужно (ну как в верху)

```
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 242
----------------
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 242
----------------
----------------
id: 4
name: батон
typePr: Хлебобулочное
cals: 242
----------------
```

Comment: в чем заключается "неверность инфы" мы должны догадаться сами?

Comment: у вас добавляется в список result, а цикл в конце написан по списку resul**st**. Это точно один и тот же список?

Comment: @Igor что бы изложить неверность инфы нужно ещё описание класса выкладывать. А это гемор читать. 
Но если нужно - вот добавил выше, по памяти сейчас набросал

Comment: @PashaPash мой прокол, поправил. Да это тот же список
лист result объявлен 1 раз вне циклов

Comment: `Да это тот же список лист result объявлен 1 раз вне циклов` очищать пробовали ? `result.clear()`

Comment: @DigitalCore сразу после объявления?

Comment: А вы можете точно сказать, какой результат ожидаете и какой в итоге получаете? Ибо сейчас это гадание на кофейной гуще и вопрос звучит (лично для меня) как "Господа есть код, он работает, но с изъяном. Помогите, как быть?", то есть без малейшего объяснения проблемы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ окей. Ща добавлю "ожидание - реальность"

Comment: Из вашего кода совершенно непонятно,  на каких данных что-то идет не так и что вообще должно происходить. Приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы, включающий в себя объявление всех переменных и заполнение массовов. который можно будет скопировать, запустить, и получить неверный результат. А так - у вас там какое-то шаманство. `temp2` зачем-то два раза присваивается подряд. Кто его знает что у вас там не так идет - может, например, у вас один и тот же объект дважды в result включается, и перетирается его первое значение cal, а вы ожидаете в result увидеть копию

Comment: @PashaPash, где эталонный вопрос про reference vs value types? Не могу найти...

Comment: То есть у вас дубли ID  в List<T> result ? поставьте точку останова на result.Add() и просмотрите что туда записывается в цикле

Comment: @AndreyMaster у вас food - это class, reference type. Когда вы делаете  food temp2 = temp[j];  int c = temp2.cal;  - **не создаете копию** того объекта, который лежал в temp[j]. Вы получаете ссылку на него. В result у вас лежит три ссылки на один и тот же объект. Если вы делаете temp2.setCalory... - вы меняете с в самом объекте.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что все ссылки ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

PS: [В чем суть отличия между ссылочными и значимыми типами данных в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/410/178988)

Comment: Как сделать что бы был новый объект, а не ссылка на старый? 
Как же в С++ было всё просто с этим делом

Comment: @AndreyMaster заменить class на struct

Comment: @PashaPash структура разве может хранить методы?

Comment: @AndreyMaster, `IClonable` смотри.

Comment: @AndreyMaster, может.