# Зачем нужен struct?

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста, зачем нужна конструкция struct(пример желателен на c#), если можно использовать простые классы?

Comment: Struct это объект. допустим при использовании массива Экземпляров класса - в массиве будут ссылки, а при использовании Структур(Объектов) - в массиве будут сами структуры.

Comment: Структуры и классы — совершенно различные штуки. Смотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/410/10105) за разъяснением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если смотреть с точки зрения абстрактного программирования, то смысла в struct действительно нет, класс является более общей концепцией, которая включает в себя struct. Но практически класс подходит не для всех задач, конкретно, класс является слишком высокоуровневой структурой.

Например, мы можем скопировать структуру в другое место просто как блок памяти. Или вывести ее в файл как неформатированный блок памяти, и так же считать ее обратно из файла. При этом мы можем задавать выравнивание членов структуры. Например, если после байта идет целое, то компилятор добавит три неиспользуемых байта, чтобы выровнять целое на границу двойного слова. Если структура используется для прямого отображения данных в файле, это может оказаться неприемлемым, но в случае структуры мы можем этим управлять.

Для структур есть термин POD (Plain Old Data), то есть это данные, которые позволяет манипулировать с собой на низком уровне, и не нуждаются в конструкторе/деструкторе. Ничего подобного с классами, разумеется, делать нельзя.

Comment: На самом деле манипулировать классами на низком уровне можно так же как объектами, только делать это нужно гораздо аккуратней. Самый простой способо запомнить и понять разницу - класс ссылочный тип, Struct - нет.

Comment: Далеко не всеми классами можно так манипулировать, а лучше никакими так не делать. Может плохо кончиться. Насчет ссылочного типа согласен, существенный момент.

Comment: Про шарп не уверен, но в том же си\плюсах - никто не запретит такого делать, а вот то что лучше так не делать - согласен =) "игры с памятью" хорошо заканчиваются только если точно знать что делаеш, так что да, так лучше не делать =)

Comment: Вы не путаете C# и C++? В C# структура — совершенно непохожая на класс штука.

Comment: И копирование памяти в C#, хотя и возможно с unsafe-кодом, _очень_ не приветствуется.

Comment: @VladD, вопрос был скорее концептуальный, а не по конкретной реализации. Ясно, что различия есть, и в С++ тоже.

Comment: @freim: Ну, я бы подчеркнул совсем другую семантику копирования (один из самых частых пунктов затыка новичков) и равенства у структур по отношению к классам в C#.

Comment: @VladD, но вопрос же был не о деталях конкретной реализации, а зачем структуры вообще нужны и какой в них смысл, если есть классы. Рассказ о нюансах копирования на этот вопрос никак не ответит.

Comment: @freim: С моей точки зрения, структуры нужну для того, чтобы можно было сформулировать семанитку значения. Сущность «комплексное число» можно, конечно, моделировать классом и перегруженными операциями сравнения, но поскольку по сути это структура, то с ней никаких перегрузок не нужно будет. Перегруженная операция сравнения и копирования и есть попытка придать ссылочному типу value-семантику.

Comment: @freim: С моей точки зрения, деатли конкретной реализации — это «на стеке» или «в куче». А смысл равенства и всего такого прописан в спеке. // Проблема со словом `struct` — это то, что в разных языках программирования оно означает очень разные вещи.

Comment: @VladD, честно говоря, я не знаю как тут спорить. С вашими тезисами я вполне согласен, не согласен лишь в том, что они являются определяющими именно в контексте данного вопроса. Но тут все субъективно - вряд ли мне удастся вас в чем-то убедить, да и вы меня не убедите. Может сойдемся на том, что зафиксируем несколько различающиеся взгляды?

Comment: @freim: Согласен! Вопрос лишь в том, что считать определяющим, а технических разногласий у нас нет.